# Robot Framework : Try to compare values of two json files

Tags: json, for-loop, robotframework

I am having some difficulty comparing any value in my json file with the response response in robotFramework.

Both are json :

```
${enterprise_json}=     Evaluate        json.dumps(${input_enterprise_json})       json
${response_json}=     Evaluate        json.dumps(${response_body})       json
```

I tried with for loop, but return fail :

```
${input_enterprise_json}=     Input       ${FILE_ENTERPRISE_JSON}

${enterprise_json}=     Evaluate        json.dumps(${input_enterprise_json})       json
${response_json}=     Evaluate        json.dumps(${response_body})       json

:FOR        ${item}     IN      ${enterprise_json}
    Should Contain Any      ${response_json}        ${item}        
END
```

Result:

[Test Execution Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb8AK.png)

Have you reference/solution for test that ?

Answer (score 0):

Or ... Is it possible to keep only values of keys of my Json file ?

```
@{list}=        Create List     @{list_values_of_my_json_file}
FOR     ${item}     IN      ${response_json}
    Should Contain      ${item}        @{list}
    # or Should Contain Any
END
```

[Explanation Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOpSI.png)